# R package xtsExtra issue to plot a multiple ts

Tags: r, time-series, xts

My aim is to get 1 plot in which there is multiple times series with an auto legend to identify the series. In my CSV file I have 5 columns (agri, food, fuel, manu, ores) starting from January,1996.

```
library(xts)
library(xtsExtra)
RuChAgri <- read.csv("https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6421260/Forum/RuChAgri.csv", sep=";")
#transform csv data according to R ts 
RuChAgri <- ts(RuChAgri, start = c(1996, 1), frequency = 1)
#try to get 1 plot with multiple ts with an auto legend
plot.xts(RuChAgri, screens = factor(1, 1), auto.legend = TRUE)
```

When I run last line I get the error:

```
Error in try.xts(x) : 
  Error in xts(x.mat, order.by = order.by, frequency = frequency(x),
 .CLASS = "ts",  :   NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
```

Does someone know what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ts` object isn't well-constructed. The series is monthly, so the frequency should be 12, not 1.

```
RuChAgri <- ts(RuChAgri, start=c(1996, 1), frequency=12)
```

Then you should convert it to an xts object and then call `plot.xts` by calling `plot`.  You really shouldn't call `plot.xts` directly, even though it tries to convert the object you give it to an xts object...

```
x <- as.xts(RuChAgri)
plot(x, screens=factor(1, 1), auto.legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks it was exactely what I wanted to do. However I have a onther question. Do you know if it's possible to add some different shape like square on the line, triange on the line, etc. I just ask this cuz then even someone who print black and white can understand the plot.

Comment: @Swiss12000: you do it the same as you would with a regular plot: add `pch=seq(ncol(x)), type="b"` to the call.